# Need help to add second condition to existing code

Tags: php

I am trying to add a second condition to existing code but it doesn't seem to be working.

The conditions are:

1. Compare two strings, from different arrays (**working**)
2. And check the value of a third string from a different array (**not
   working**)

Here is the working code without the second condition: http://pastebin.com/bfpNb9zw

**Here is my attempt:**

Basically, the bit I am trying to get working is this part `&& ($ca = '')` `&& ($ca = '0')` `&& ($ca = '1')` but it seems $ca is not able to be read outside the loop

```
if(!function_exists('lookup')){
function lookup($chain, $type) {
    $cacount = count($chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
    for($j = 0; $j < $cacount; $j++) {
        $count = count($chain['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence']);
        $exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString', 'ia5String');
        $oid = array('id-at-commonName');
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            foreach($exists as $field) {
                if(
                    array_key_exists($field, $chain['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
                    in_array($chain['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
                ) {
                    $value = $chain['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
                    return $value;
                    $ca = '';
                    if(isset($chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue']['cA'])) {
                    $ca = $chain['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue']['cA'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
}

if (lookup($chain, 'subject') != lookup($chain, 'issuer') && ($ca == '')) {
    echo 'end entity';
    } 
elseif (lookup($chain, 'subject') != lookup($chain, 'issuer') && ($ca == '0')) {
    echo 'secondary ca';
    } 
elseif (lookup($chain, 'subject') != lookup($chain, 'issuer') && ($ca == '1')) {
    echo 'primary ca';
    } else { 
    echo 'Root';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `=`, which sets the value of `$ca`. You should be using `===` to check the value, instead.

Example:

```
if (lookup($chain, 'subject') != lookup($chain, 'issuer') && ($ca === '')) {
    echo 'end entity';
} 
elseif (lookup($chain, 'subject') != lookup($chain, 'issuer') && ($ca === '0')) {
    echo 'secondary ca';
} 
elseif (lookup($chain, 'subject') != lookup($chain, 'issuer') && ($ca === '1')) {
     echo 'primary ca';
} else { 
    echo 'Root';
}
```

Comment: woops! okay. fixed that but getting this now `Notice:  Undefined variable: ca` - here is a copy of the input if needed http://pastebin.com/fhe8BdnB

Comment: In your code (user3436467), `$ca` looks like it is set as a local variable inside the `function`, so of course, `$ca` won't be present outside the `function`.

Comment: @Dwright, makes sense, but how can i make it available outside the function ?

Comment: @user3436467 You never initialize `$ca`. You set it inside an `if` statement in a loop, so there's some chance it never gets set. And as DWright says, even that's in a function, so it isn't defined outside the function. You need to use a global variable (bad) or set the value some other way, such as passing it by reference to your function.

Comment: i added `$ca = '';` outside the loop but it doesn't seem to be updating when it goes in the loop

Comment: @user3436467 It still only exists inside the function. You need to read about variable scoping.

Comment: If $ca is currently genuinely local to the function, you could define `var $ca;` before the call to the function, then add $ca as a third reference parameter of the function `&$ca`) and calling the function would set it it, but given that you call the function multiple times in one set of conditions, that does not sound safe, either.

Comment: i tried adding `global $ca;` inside the function but still not updating.. sorry,  a newbie here.

Comment: @user3436467 You still have to initialize it somewhere outside the function if you want to use a global. It may also be that you have a logic error in the function itself, but there's a bit too much going on there (and not enough information in the question) to assess that.

Comment: That's certainly one way to do things, however, you'd need to make sure $ca is declared outside the function.  Further, you need to know that $ca will be whatever the last call to the function sets it to.

Comment: i thought i am declaring it by doing this before the function `$ca = '';` and then inside the loop `global $ca;` before `if(set(..` -- if its not clear what i am asking for would you be open to a chat? or post sample code that i can try ?

Comment: @user3436467 it really isn't clear what you're saying. What makes you think it isn't getting set correctly? In any case, the problem you originally posted --- that you couldn't add a second condition in your `if` statement --- is fixed. Would you please accept this as the answer and post a new question addressing the logic problems in your function? We try not to have questions turn into "moving targets" here. :)

Comment: okay sure.. ill think about it a bit more before posting. thank you